# How to to do FaceCrop in unity3d?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, shader

Anyone Find how to Crop face in unity for Mobile Devices.
   Do like,Take screenShot and apply in Material,Which as Having `MaskTexture Shader.Mask-texture` shader will having `Default`.Check Below link for masking.

Visit http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=Texture_Mask

Thanks,
Adi.